# Background Image full-screen fit without any cut

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set a full-screen background image (1366x854) with css. I've tried in many ways peeking online but I can't set my image as it is. It is possible to have it full-screen without get cut parts? The img below is just a prototype and code is really basic. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> LIVE </title>
<link href="css/Live.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>



body { 
 background: url(Live.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 background-size: contain 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: remove contain and keep only `100% 100%` and no need `fixed`

Comment: Thanks for answer..but unfortunately it doesn't work..

Comment: Do you want to image to cover the entire background?

Comment: Yes but without have any cut part if it possible. I've tried with background-size: cover; but still I have some parts cut

Comment: I see, `margin:0;height:100vh` to body?

Comment: That works but i Lose the img proportion..

Comment: for sure you will lose the proportion if you want to cover full screen. If you want to keep the ratio use `cover`

Comment: In this strange way it works, when I scroll with mouse I see the rest of the pic. Maybe this method could be write better... body { 
 margin:0;
 height:854px;
 background: url(Live.png) no-repeat center center; 
 background-size: contain 100% 100%;
} With cover as size it's better